# Use of brace and multiple lines in function mapping notation

Tags: functions, soft-question, notation

If $f$ is a function under which each element of set $A$ has an image in set $B$ and under which $x$ is mapped to $y$, which of the following notations is more common, correct, rigorous and/or accepted?

$$f:\begin{array}{l}A\to B\\x\mapsto y\\\end{array}\tag{1}$$
$$f:\begin{array}{l}x\mapsto y\\A\to B\\\end{array}\tag{2}$$
$$f:\left\{\begin{array}{l}A\to B\\x\mapsto y\\\end{array}\right.\tag{3}$$
$$f:\left\{\begin{array}{l}x\mapsto y\\A\to B\\\end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$

I believe $(3)$ is standard. I ask because my textbook offers no examples of simultaneously describing the domain, codomain, and mapping of a function.

If you know of any other more respectable notations, such as $f:A\to B:x\mapsto y$, which I have not seen before but I feel is definitely valid, please mention so, but also indicate which of $(1)$ through $(4)$ is the most preferable of the group.

I realize this question could be interpreted as subjective. I ask because I do not want to seem poorly versed in the subject when writing. I have attempted to phrase this question in the most objective way possible, but I am open to suggestions and revisions.